# On 'A proof of ABC conjecture after Mochizuki'

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, soft-question

It has been pointed out to me that Go Yamashita has a preprint on his website, [*A proof of ABC conjecture after Mochizuki*](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~gokun/DOCUMENTS/abc_ver6.pdf), that is not in the [RIMS Preprints online archive](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/).

- Is that work intended for publication?
- Does it present sketches of Mochizuki's main arguments or is it a detailed presentation of his works?

Comment: The first question is too speculative. As for the 2nd, it is clearly a serious effort at a surveying a large amount of work in a more limited amount of space, and beyond saying that one probably gets into the realm of "opinion on a preprint" which isn't meant to be a focus for MO questions.  Anyway, the footnote at the bottom of page 6 is interesting.

Comment: An aggressive footnote! How bizarre

Comment: I'm voting to close this on the basis of the Meta discussion on what is suitable for MO: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/927/what-is-our-policy-on-asking-about-correctness-of-preprints .  Is there a real focussed  question here?

Comment: @Lucia, thank you for your comment. I'm not really asking about *correctness*. I'm just surprised that the preprint didn't appear on the RIMS Preprints server, so I wondered if it is actually intended for publication. The second question is maybe more focussed ad it's about defining the scope of a long paper since the abstract doesn't address it clearly in my opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question that should be sent directly to the author of the paper being asked about.