# Baby $abc$ conjecture for $n$-th roots

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation, abc-conjecture, powerful-numbers

Is there any progress on a “baby $abc$ conjecture” where you restrict attention to rational approximations of $n$-th roots?

Let $r/s$ be a very close approximation to $(t/u)^{1/n}$, so that
$$
|u\cdot r^n - t\cdot s^n| = a
$$
is small.  We thus have a pseudo-$abc$-triple with $c$ being the larger of $u\cdot r^n$ and $t\cdot s^n$, and $q=\frac{\log c}{\log(arstu)}$.

**Example**: the fifth root of $109$ is very close to $23/9$, so we get
$$
2+109\cdot 9^5=23^5,\quad 5\log(23)/\log(45126) = 1.4628,
$$ not quite as good as the $1.6299$ it gets as an $abc$ triple where you use that $9 = 3^2$ but still good enough to make it the “best” known approximation of any root.

Is anything known about $q$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: Please use TeX on this site, and also use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Applying Liouville's theorem on diophantine approximation to the algebraic number $(t/u)^{1/n}$ would get some preliminary bound.  Improving this bound seems related to the problem of trying to find effective versions of the Thue-Siegel-Roth theorem.  In this regard, the answers here may be relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58856/advances-and-difficulties-in-effective-version-of-thue-roth-siegel-theorem

Comment: I believe this approach is known for searching for high quality triples.

Comment: The first page of Baker’s paper “Rational Approximations to Certain Algebraic Numbers” promises a constructive bound on the closeness of rational approximations of $nth$ roots of rationals, but the rest of the paper is behind a paywall and I can’t find even a non-paywalled STATEMENT of the theorem elsewhere! Can anyone give me a link to a statement of Baker’s result, or just state it here?